# make parallax mouse effect responsive using svg images HTML - SCSS

Tags: javascript, html, svg, sass, responsive

I am creating a landing page, I used svg images for the home of the site.
On the left I have a title and a button, which are in the ***data** div*, while on the left there are 3 svg images, which are in the ***banner-images** div* and have a mouse parallax effect.
Now, everything is well placed if full screen, but when I resize the page everything gets messed up.
I have problems managing the 3 images and I don't know if what I wrote is correct.

I have no preferences for the responsive layout.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', move);

function move(e) {
  this.querySelectorAll('.moving-img').forEach(layer => {
    const speed = layer.getAttribute('data-speed');

    const x = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX * speed) / 150;
    const y = (window.innerHeight - e.pageY * speed) / 150;

    layer.style.transform = "translateX(" + x + "px) translateY(" + y + "px)";
  })
}
```

```css
/* ------------------ Imports ------------------ */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap");

/* ------------------ Colors ------------------ */
$blackBackgroundColor: #121212;
$blackDivsColor: #0c0c0c;
$whiteText: #fff;
$whiteBackgroundColor: #fff;
$whiteDivsColor: #e9e9e9;
$blackText: #121212;
$purple: #7b49db;

/* ------------------ Fonts ------------------ */
$bodyFont: "Rubik",
sans-serif;

/* ------------------ GLOBAL ------------------ */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: $bodyFont;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 100% auto;
}


/* ------------------ HOME ------------------ */
#home {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: $whiteBackgroundColor;
  
  .home-container {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    .data {
      color: $blackText;
      
      .home-title {
        font-size: 15vh;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      
      .home-button {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: $purple;
        color: $whiteText;
        padding: 20px 50px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    }
    
    .banner-images {
      position: relative;
      width: 600px;
      height: 750px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      
      img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      
      #up-hand, #down-hand {
        z-index: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/main.css">
  <title>Tap-it</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Home section -->
  <section id="home">
    <div class="home-container container">
      <div class="data">
        <h1 class="home-title">TAP-IT</h1>
        <a href="#" class="home-button">Get Started</a>
      </div>

      <div class="banner-images">
        <img src="./assets/images/banner-up-hand.svg" alt="banner" class="moving-img" id="up-hand" data-speed="-2">
        <img src="./assets/images/banner-down-hand.svg" alt="banner" class="moving-img" id="down-hand" data-speed="1">
        <img src="./assets/images/banner-phone.svg" alt="banner" class="moving-img" id="phone" data-speed="-1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

I don't know how to help with the code because I used images and the snippet can't handle them, so ask me anything you need. 
If you need the 3 images, I'll leave them here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5c47bfcc566d33497e1e1accb33e942f20210615171854/23edfa

Comment: [Here's a working pen with the SVGs inlined into the `<img>` tags.](https://codepen.io/kdau00/pen/NWpeOqx) I'll be experimenting on it to find an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [pen I built of your code for testing](https://codepen.io/kdau00/pen/NWpeOqx), the only real issue I saw with smaller page widths was that a horizontal scrollbar popped in and out as the parallax changed. Let us know if there's something else not working.

To fix that, first I made the parallax distance traveled constant across different window sizes by changing the calculation from your original:

```js
const x = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX * speed) / 150;
const y = (window.innerHeight - e.pageY * speed) / 150;
```

to one that takes the cursor position as a proportion of the window size:

```js
const x = (window.innerWidth - e.pageX) / window.innerWidth * speed * 6;
const y = (window.innerHeight - e.pageY) / window.innerHeight * speed * 6;
```

(The factor `6` was my best effort to recreate your factor `150` as it would apply to a maximized window on a 1080p screen.)

Since the speeds are `-2`, `1` and `-1`, the furthest to the right (and thus off the page horizontally) that one of the images can be offset is now `6px`. So, to ensure that the images will stay within the window, just this had to be added in CSS:

```css
.banner-images {
    /* ... */
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the js code works much better now, but the problem is still there, if it can help, I need something like this: https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/robotics/
(try resizing the window).
If you need the code, you can find it here: https://github.com/h3webdevtuts/Website5-Robotics/blob/master/style.scss


(I took it from this video: https://youtu.be/fsIuaeZ0mhA)

Comment: If all you want is to rearrange the elements on the page when the page resizes, then what you want to look into are [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).